# Multiple characters in Python ord function

Tags: python, hex, ord

Programming beginner here. (Python 2.7)

Is there a work around for using more than a single character for Python's ord function?

For example, I have a hex string '\xff\x1a' which I'd like the decimal value for so that I can sum it with other hex strings. However ord only accepts a single hex string character.

Thank you!

Comment: remember that strings are iterable by character...

Comment: How the solution below, Micuzzo?

Comment: What do you mean by decimal value? `ord()` works on a byte, and that string contains two bytes.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary yes you are correct. My intention is to sum a series of hex values and from my understanding the best way to do this is to convert them into a integer and then sum... then reconvert to hex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Strings are iterable, so you can loop through the string, use `ord` and add the results:

```
your_sum = sum([ord(i) for i in '\xff\x1a'])
```

Comment: Thank you. This seem to work very well. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to up vote you...

Comment: Just mark the solution as answer, and I will be rewarded.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what purpose does this code serve?

Comment: I will copy what I wrote to Ashwini here:My intention is to sum a series of hex values and from my understanding the best way to do this is to convert them into a integer and then sum... then reconvert to hex.

Comment: @micuzzo: You don't have a series of hex values, you just have a series of bytes. `'\x40'` is just one byte, print it and you'll see `@`.

Comment: [Gematria!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gematria)

Comment: Come on people! Use a generator expression rather than wasting memory and CPU cycles creating an intermediate list: `your_sum = sum(ord(i) for i in '\xff\x1a')`.